# Measure RGB% of an Image

Tags: java, image, rgb

I want to measure Red, Green, and Blue color percentage of an image. I can get the RGB values of each pixel through getRGB() but cant separate R,G,B each. My code is returning value like `rgb 167 163 164`. How can I measure each one separately?

```
public class RGB {
    public static final String IMG = "/home/aritra/workspace/oopencv/picture/Pic652.jpg";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedImage img;

        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(IMG));

            int[][] pixelData = new int[img.getHeight() * img.getWidth()][3];
            int[] rgb;

            int counter = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < img.getWidth(); i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < img.getHeight(); j++){
                    rgb = getPixelData(img, i, j);

                }  
                //System.out.println(counter);
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static int[] getPixelData(BufferedImage img, int x, int y) {
    int argb = img.getRGB(x, y);
    int  red[]={0};
    int rgb[] = new int[] {
        (argb >> 16) & 0xff, //red
        (argb >>  8) & 0xff, //green
        (argb      ) & 0xff  //blue
    };

    System.out.println("rgb: " + rgb[0] + " " + rgb[1] + " " + rgb[2]);

    return rgb;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to calculate it on your for after rgb = getPixelData(

rgb[0] is RED, rgb[1] is GREEN abd rgb[2] is BLUE

The values ranges from 0 to 254